# Splitting a hexadecimal string into chunks in Python

Tags: python, string, hex

I have this part of code in Python:

```
for line in response.body.split("\n"):
    if line != "": 
        opg = int(line.split(" ")[2])
        opc = int(line.split(" ")[3])
        value = line.split(" ")[5]
        if command == 'IDENTIFY':
            if opg==opcodegroupr and opc==opcoder:
                print line
                ret['success'] = "IDENTIFY: The value is %s " % (value)
                self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
                self.finish()
```

Variable 'line' is made in this way:

```
1363005087 2459546910990453036 151 88 4 0x15000000
```

Every field is an integer, but not the last field. The last field is an hex number.

I would take this hex number and after split byte per byte. For example I would that 
0x15000000 was splitted in 15 00 00 00.

How can I do? I tried with value.encode("hex") but dowsn't work fine... value is a string? I don't know how consider this variable..

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do with the hex value?

Comment: The hex value is a payload of the response of my sensors to some commands I send them. There are informations that I want to know and print to the user in an html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the hexadecimal value is already text, you don't need to do any more conversion:

```
>>> text = "0x15000000"
>>> text = text[2:]  # remove literal type prefix
>>> text = text.zfill(len(text) + len(text) % 2)  # pad with zeros for even digits
>>> ' '.join(text[i: i+2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2))  # split into 2-digit chunks
'15 00 00 00'
```

(edited per [@tobias-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k)'s suggestion about zero-padding)

Comment: Remember to add a leading zero if the string has odd number of places; otherwise you will end up with something like `'12 34 5'`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def split_hex(value):
    value = value[2:] if len(value) % 2 == 0 else "0" + value[2:]
    return " ".join(value[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(value), 2))
```

Note that if the hex number has an odd number of places we have to add a leading zero to properly split it into bytes.

```
print split_hex("0x1234567")
>>> 01 23 45 67
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = line.split(" ")[5]
```

`value` is a string because you didn’t convert it. You can make an int out of a hex string using `int(value, 16)`, e.g.

```
>>> int('0x15000000', 16)
352321536
```